# Realizo un UPDATE con PHP y MySQL y perfecto pero vuelvo actualizar y no lo hace, no sobrescribe dos veces

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

He logrado realizar un **UPDATE** con **PHP** en **MySQL** de mi **phpMyAdmin**, lo logro con éxito, pero luego quiero actualizar una segunda vez y ya no se sobrescriben, les muestro la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ejempo:** Actualizo el campo ***CONDUCTOR:*** Luis Perez > *VEHICULO/PLACA:* AVEO/AMARILLO > *FRANJA HORARIA:* 930 a 12 > *ESTADO DEL DELIVERY:* En Camino.

Guardo cambios con el boton asignar y se actualiza la info en la Base de Datos, pero cuando quiero actualizar por ejemplo luego u solo campo, naturalmente los demas se quedan igual, pero cuando quiero actualizar para utilizar otro conducto u otro horario es ahí el problema y no se actualiza,/no realiza el UPDATE/ no se sobrescriben los datos.

Les dejo mi Código PHP:

```
    <?php 
include("conexion.php");
require_once 'conexion.php';

$npedido = $_POST["npedido"];
$conductor = $_POST["conductor"];
$placa_modelo = $_POST["placa_modelo"];
$franja_horaria = $_POST["franja_horaria"];
$estadod = $_POST["estadod"];

// Verificar pedido
$query   = "SELECT 'conductor','placa_modelo','franja_horaria','estadod' FROM creadas WHERE npedido='$npedido' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    // Sí existe el pedido
    $query   = "UPDATE creadas SET conductor='$conductor',placa_modelo='$placa_modelo',franja_horaria='$franja_horaria',estadod='$estadod' WHERE npedido='$npedido' ";

    if ($db->query($query)) {
        echo "<script> alert('Usted ha cambiado el estado del pedido, por favor ejecute el delivery');
                        location.href = 'delivery.php';
                        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al Registrar, vuevla a intentarlo" . mysqli_error($db);
    }
} else {
    echo "<script> alert('El número de pedido que intenta ingresar no existe, por favor verifiquelo e intente de nuevo.');
    location.href = 'dashboard.php';
    </script>";
    // No existe el pedido

}
?>
```

Este es mi HTML:

```
<form class="form-group" action="modificar_delivery2.php" method="post">
                                                    <td>                                                    
                                                        <div class="form-group">                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="conductor" id="conductor" required>
                                                                    <option disabled>Seleccione el nombre del conductor</option>
                                                                    <option>Julio Perez</option>
                                                                    <option>Luis Rojas</option>
                                                                    <option>Jose garcia</option>
                                                                    <option>Mario hernandez</option>                                                                                                                    
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">                                                                
                                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="placa_modelo" id="placa_modelo" required>
                                                                    <option disabled>Seleccione el vehículo </option>
                                                                    <option>AVEO/AMARILLO/AA131GG</option>
                                                                    <option>OPTRA/AZUL/DCA34H</option>                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>    
                                                        </div>                                                        
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="franja_horaria" id="franja_horaria" required>
                                                                    <option disabled>Seleccione un horario de envío</option>
                                                                    <option>9:30a.m. a 11:30a.m.</option>
                                                                    <option>12:00m. a 2:30p.m.</option>
                                                                    <option> 2:30p.m. a 4:00p.m.</option>                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                                    
                                                    </td>   
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="form-group">                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                <select class="form-control form-control-line" name="estadod" id="estadod" required>
                                                                    <option disabled>Seleccione un estado</option>                                                                        >
                                                                    <option>ya va</option>
                                                                    <option>En camino</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>                                            
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
                                                    ASIGNAR</button>
                                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                                        <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Usted está asignando un DELIVERY</h5>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                                        </button>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="modal-body">                                                                             
                                                                    ¿ está de acuerdo con asignar un DELIVERY a este pedido? Recuerde que al elegir la opción SI, automaticamente el Clienté se dará por enterado.
                                                                    <br>
                                                                    <br>                                                                     
                                                                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="npedido" id="npedido"  placeholder="Por seguridad coloque # Pedido">                                                                          
                                                                    </div>                                                                    
                                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Si</button>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </form>
```

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error?

Comment: Al inicio del código estás invocando el archivo **conexión.php** con `include` y luego con `require_once`. Revisaste eso?

Comment: En la tabla de la imagen hay tres columnas que no están en el código HTML.

Comment: No arroja ningun `error`, ya borré `requiere_once` y las tres columnas que salen son datos que estoy trayendo de la base de datos, no las estoy afectando con los cambios.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Javascript para validar o procesar (AJAX) el formulario? Si es así, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código correspondiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, eliminé el modal que estaba utilizando con bootstrap que era lo que me estaba trayendo conflicto.